# Way to force image to reload from server

Tags: javascript

I've seen all of the other posts on similar issues with setAttribute() in IE, but can't seem to get any of the workarounds to, er, work (specifically for the src attribute of an img element.

The example:

```
function reloadCaptcha(sImgElementId) {
    var oImgElement = document.getElementById(sImgElementId);
    oImgElement.setAttribute('src', oImgElement.src);
    return false;
}
```

And the img element:

```
<img id="nlc" name="nlc" src="/inc_captcha.asp" onClick="javascript:reloadCaptcha('nlc'); return false;" />
```

It just reloads the src. Works like a charm in Chrome and FF. Nada in IE.

How can I make this work in IE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it will reliably reload your captcha image:

```
oImgElement.src = oImgElement.src + '?' + Math.random();
```

Comment: You win. I forgot about the caching problem with IE.

Comment: +1, this is the standard way to break image caching, but done this way, it may only work once and won't work if there were any other parameters on the URL.  To make it work repeatedly, you would need to first remove the old random value if it exists.

Comment: darn, is there really no better way to do it than this? I had been previously using an iframe and reloading that, which worked fine, but I was trying to get away from that. Also, i didn't include it in my example, but there is one other parameter in the url, so the random value querystring won't work.

Comment: @robarwebservices: Sure it will. Just replace the `?` with a `&`. Or just use `oImgElement.src = oImgElement.src + '&_t=' + (+(new Date()))`.

Comment: Yes, that did it. So as a best practice, should I leave the `setAttribute()` line as-is, and ALSO include the `oImgElement.src = oImgElement.src + '&_t=' + (+(new Date()))` below it, or should I get rid of the `setAttribute` as redundant?

Comment: Yes, `setAttribute` would be redundant.